# Detect HTML tags in a string

Tags: php

I need to detect whether a string contains HTML tags.

```
if(!preg_match('(?<=<)\w+(?=[^<]*?>)', $string)){ 
    return $string;
}
```

The above regex gives me an error:

```
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '\'
```

I'm not well up on regex so not sure what the problem was. I tried escaping the \ and it didn't do anything.

Is there a better solution than regex? If not, what would be the correct regex to work with the preg_match?

Comment: add `/` to the beginning and end of your regex string

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
if($string != strip_tags($string)) {
    // contains HTML
}
```

The benefit of this over a regex is it's easier to understand, however I could not comment on the speed of execution of either solution.

Comment: +1 That's the easiest way to detect the presence of tags. You don´t even need `strlen`.

Comment: Nice answer! Much simpler, although I think generally regexpressions are extremely fast.

Comment: this is indeed a better solution than a regex :)

Comment: This will also tell <asdfasdfasdf> a html tag.

Comment: The above code will return a false positive if the string contains any control characters like /n /r...

Comment: @R1CHY_RICH: Can you provide a sample case for the false positive you describe? The following emits "no html" for me: `$s = "hello\r\nworld";

if (strip_tags($s) != $s) {
  echo 'contains html';
}
else {
  echo 'no html';
}`

Comment: Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778035/how-to-check-if-string-contents-have-any-html-in-it

Comment: "My weight is <100kg." will also be detected as HTML content.

Comment: strip tags even sees this as containing HTML "price <0.5 for a week" even though there is no closing tag. Basically <charwithoutwhitespace is HTML

Answer (score 12):

you need to 'delimit' the regex with some character or another.  Try this:

```
if(!preg_match('#(?<=<)\w+(?=[^<]*?>)#', $string)){ 
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Test with this sentence: 'the weight of a cherry < apple but > raspberry. It is <2g.'

Comment: (?<=<)\/?[a-zA-z]+\s*(?=[^<]*?>) works better for me

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to detect/replace certain tags: This function will search for certain html tags and encapsulate them in brackets - which is pretty senseless - just modify it to whatever you want to do with the tags.

```
$html = preg_replace_callback(
    '|\</?([a-zA-Z]+[1-6]?)(\s[^>]*)?(\s?/)?\>|',
    function ($found) {
        if(isset($found[1]) && in_array(
            $found[1], 
            array('div','p','span','b','a','strong','center','br','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','hr'))
        ) {
            return '[' . $found[0] . ']';
        };
    },
    $html  
);
```

Explaination of the regex:

```
\< ... \>   //start and ends with tag brackets
\</?        //can start with a slash for closing tags
([a-zA-Z]+[1-6]?)    //the tag itself (for example "h1")
(\s[^>]*)? //anything such as class=... style=... etc.
(\s?/)?     //allow self-closing tags such as <br />
```

Answer (score 4):

If purpose is just to check if string contain html tag or not. No matter html tags are valid or not. Then you can try this.

```
function is_html($string) {
  // Check if string contains any html tags.
  return preg_match('/<\s?[^\>]*\/?\s?>/i', $string);
}
```

This works for all valid or invalid html tags. You can check confirm here https://regex101.com/r/2g7Fx4/3

Comment: Why the case-sensitive pattern modifier?  Why is `>` escaped in the negated character class?

Comment: Well, the following text is then considered HTML: The case where some number <2 and another >8 is considered to contain HTML

Answer (score 2):

I would use `strlen()` because if you don't, then a character-by-character comparison is done and that can be slow, though I would expect the comparison to quit as soon as it found a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to allow **defined tags** only! You don't want the user to type the `<script>` tag, which could cause a XSS vulnerability.

Try it with:

```
$string = '<strong>hello</strong>';
$pattern = "/<(p|span|b|strong|i|u) ?.*>(.*)<\/(p|span|b|strong|i|u)>/"; // Allowed tags are: <p>, <span>, <b>, <strong>, <i> and <u>
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

if (!empty($matches)) {
    echo 'Good, you have used a HTML tag.';
}
else {
    echo 'You didn\'t use a HTML tag or it is not allowed.';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a backreference `\1` to ensure balanced tags?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML in general is a hard problem, there is some good material here:

- [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)
- [Parsing: Beyond Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/parsing-beyond-regex.html)

But regarding your question ('better' solution) - can be more specific regarding what you are trying to achieve, and what tools are available to you?

Answer (score 0):

If your not good at regular expressions (like me) I find lots of regex libraries out there that usually help me accomplish my task.

Here is a little tutorial that will [explain what your trying to do in php.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

Here is [one of those libraries](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL) I was referring to.