# How can I check if the value of a textarea has HTML in it using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am currently using jQuery to check if the textarea has HTML in it: (and I will continue to use this)

```
   if ($('textarea#newMessage').val().match(/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/)) {
      $('textarea#newMessage').focus();
      $('#error').html('Error: HTML is not aloud. Please remove all of the HTML in your message to continue.')
      .click(function() { $('#newMessage').focus(); })
      .stop(true,true)
      .fadeIn(800)
      .delay(1500)
      .fadeOut(200);
      return false;
   }
```

But, how can I use PHP to do this same thing? If someone disables JavaScript, they can easily submit the form with HTML in it. Is there a way for PHP to do this also?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732758/detect-html-tags-in-a-string

Comment: a simpler expression would be `/<.*?>/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will catch tags and no text.

```js
$textareaname = (isset($_POST['textareaname']))
                ? $_POST['textareaname']
                : '';

if ($textareaname !== strip_tags($_POST['textareaname']))
{
    // contains tags
}

elseif (trim($textareaname ) === '')
{
    // textarea is empty
}

else
{
    // OK! do something
}
```

Notes:

1. If the form is sent without anything in the textarea,
   `$_POST['textareaname']` won't exist and PHP will throw an error when
   you try to use it.
2. If someone sends nothing but spaces `trim()` will catch it.

Comment: I kinda actually rather have the error message. I would accept your answer, but I rather have the error message as if they don't have JavaScript enabled, they might be trying to bypass my jQuery checking, which would mean that it should show an error even with the PHP. But thanks so much for telling me about `trim()`!! :) Also, I might not want to forgo the jQuery method because I am going to be using AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: @Nathan: In light of your comment, I updated the code to check for tags and empty textareas with nothing but spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much! :) What does the `?` and other stuff do in the variable? Is it part of `isset()`?

Comment: `a ? b : c` is a shortcut for `if(a) b else c`. For a better explanation see [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in the manual or [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($text != strip_tags($text))
    // text contains html
```

see [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match("/<[^>]*>/", $_POST['textareaname'])){
   //contains html tags
} else {
   //dosomething...
}
```

Comment: Will this check if the textarea is empty? (I also needed this too) If so thanks also.

Comment: edited.. remove html tags and check if the textarea is empty.

Comment: Will this remove them or show an error if it has HTML tags in it?

Comment: For increased usability you could have PHP automatically strip the tags instead of requiring the user to do it. Also: `isset($_POST['textareaname'])` will check if the textarea is empty. See [isset](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in the manual.

Comment: @Herbet What if someone puts in some spaces? Will it count as not empty with `isset()`? I have been trying to figure that out for a while because right now I just use `if($value = '') {` and that allows the user to just type a space and send it without anything in it.

Comment: isset makes sure the array key (in this case "textareaname") has actually been set. You should use it to insure that the variable $_POST['textareaname'] exists before trying to do anything with it. See my answer for more details. @RiaD - What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: @RiaD - my apologies. Kakashi edited his answer and I didn't catch it. I understand what you're talking about now. :p

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match() with the regular expression you already got. And by the way: Instead of "aloud" you probably mean "allowed" ;)

Comment: Yep, I meant "allowed" LOL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you may use exactly same regexp via `preg_match`

Besides, you want to restrict HTML to avoid changing anything in your code structure.
So, you may just use `htmlspecialchars` to print HTML as plain text.
But If you really need check, are they exists, you may just check symbols `<` and `>` that can break you markup by `preg_match('~[<>]~',..)` or just to `strpos`'es

Comment: Yeah, well the reason I'm restricting HTML is because the textarea is a reply thing, and when you reply it gets added to the database and an email gets send. I don't want extra HTML in the email. (someone could easily add JavaScript to the reply with `<script>` tags and mess something up)