# Reading JSON in this scenario?

Tags: php, json, yql

I am trying to parse rss feeds from various sources,one of such source is this:`http://feeds.feedburner.com/DiscoveryNews-Top-Stories`

But this source is giving me some weird json data like this:

```
"item": [
    {
     "title": [
      "Snazzy Science Photos of the Week (August 10-16)",
      {
       "type": "html",
       "content": "Snazzy Science Photos of the Week (August 10-16)"
      }
     ],
     "description": [
      "Glowing rabbits, treasure-hunting badgers and a case of mistaken UFO identity help round out this week&#039;s photos.<img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/DiscoveryNews-Top-Stories/~4/S6Urfvdw2DQ\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\"/>",
      {
       "type": "html",
       "content": "Glowing rabbits, treasure-hunting badgers and a case of mistaken UFO identity help round out this week&#039;s photos."
      }
     ],
```

Currently,I'm using the following code to get titles of the posts:

```
if(isset($jit->title->content)){
                $title = $decoded_json->query->results->item->title->content;
            }else{
                $title = $decoded_json->query->results->item->title;
            }
```

But the above code fails when I try to parse Discovery news feed.Please help?

[EDIT]:
I'm using YQL to get the equivalent JSON from the source.This is the [link](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20feed%20where%20url=%22http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc)

Comment: I don't see any JSON there only XML available.

Comment: @RajatSaxena Can you show (jsfiddle?) how you're consuming the YQL/json feed?

Comment: I'm parsing it from PHP only,I'm not using javascript.Also,I've pasted the PHP code I'm using in my question only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is packing up the elements as an array:

```
"title": [
          "No Battery Required for This Wireless Device",
          {
              "type": "html",
              "content": "No Battery Required for This Wireless Device"
          }
         ],
```

You can read the first element like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url=%22http://feeds.feedburner.com/DiscoveryNews-Top-Stories%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc';
$data = substr(file_get_contents($url), 7, -2);
$json = json_decode($data);
foreach ($json->query->results->item as $item)
{
    echo "Title: ", $item->title[0], "\nDescription: ", $item->description[0], "\n";
    echo "==================================================\n\n";
}
```

Or using SimpleXML library:

```
$url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/DiscoveryNews-Top-Stories?format=xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo "Title: ", $item->title, "\nDescription: ", $item->description, "\n";
    echo "==================================================\n\n";
}
```

Comment: @RajatSaxena haha :P it became an habit to post that my bad. By the way is there a reason you don't want to read the XML directly?

Comment: Nah,I seem to like JSON.

Comment: @RajatSaxena in case its of your interest I've posted at the bottom a simple example of how to read it with SimpleXML ;)

Comment: Do you know how to determine whether the string is text or html,in php?

Comment: @RajatSaxena here is one good way to check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/5732812/342740 however if the strings are encoded you need to convert them back into HTML.