# PHP to Display JSON/HTML Return

Tags: php, html, json, parsing

So I'm using PHP to display data from an API that outputs JSON. One of the JSON data fields has an output that includes HTML used to format the text. My problem is how do I use PHP to display the JSON but then have the returned data with the HTML in it render the HTML.

Here's the PHP...

```
echo "Description:".$results['description']."</br>";
```

The ['description'] field, returns information such as..

```
<p>This would be an example of returned description.<br> It includes HTML.</p>
```

So how do I break out of PHP to display the return data's HTML?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php ?

Comment: How do I insert the html_entity_decode()?

Comment: Like this `echo "Description:".html_entity_decode($results['description'])."</br>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the HTML.

Read [PHP html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Then you can now do it like this

`echo "Description:".html_entity_decode($results['description'])."</br>";`

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution, it decoded the html being output. Thanks to the community for your help.

```
echo "Description:".html_entity_decode($results['description'])."</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to swap it around and do this:

```
<?php
// PHP code here
?>

Description:<?php $results['description']; ?></br>
```

Comment: That keeps the return data within the PHP though, I need to break out of it or specify that the data being returned has HTML.

Comment: @JohnChase Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732758/detect-html-tags-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, first write a php code to decode json data,

```
<?php
$json  = '{"value1": 1}'; 
$data  = json_decode($json);
$value =  $data->{'value1'};
?>
```

Then, in html use tag like this to show the php content,

```
<p>The Value from json is:<?php echo $value; ?></p>
```

This will give the output

```
The value from json is 1
```

Hope this helps.