# PHP - If string contains '<' or '>' - strpos()

Tags: php, html, string, strpos

I want to do a simple kind of test to see if a string contains any HTML.

In this case if the `$string` variable is `test` or `<test>` it returns `no` for me:

```
$string = 'test';
if(strpos($string,'<') !== 'false'){
    echo 'no';
}else{
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Is there a better way to check if a string contains HTML? I don't want to do anything to the string just check if it has HTML tags?

Comment: `!== false` - compare to boolean not a string

Comment: I think you should use an HTML Parser. '<' is not mandatory a HTML tag.

Comment: definitely a typo question

Comment: @Jens I think you'll find the < is pretty much mandatory when opening any html tag

Comment: @Dale yes, but the presence of `<` doesn't guarantee the string contains HTML.

Comment: @Dale But x<1 is not an html tag bt contains <

Comment: ah I see your point, though you would surely use &lt; in your edge case example

Comment: @Dale not if i see it as a string not as HTML part

Comment: I've got you, slow to wake today, the coffe helps

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if($string != strip_tags($string)) {
    // contains HTML
}
```

Took the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732758/detect-html-tags-in-a-string)

Comment: Please mark as duplicate, instead of duplicating answers.